# How to improve performance on two thread accesing a collection of items concurrently

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-3.5

I'm implementing Producer/Consumer aproach on a .net project 3.5

**There is only one producer and one consumer each running on its own thread**

The `CheckOrderToProcess` method checks a table that match certain conditions and adds them to a list (Producer)

The `bgOrdenes_DoWork` method takes each item on the list and performs some logic (Consumer)

I want to avoid locking the whole list `lstOrderToProcessto` in order to improve performance, I tried to use `ConcurrentQueue` but I can not upgrade to .net 4.0 due to limitations that this is going to be used in projects that cannot be upgraded to 4.0

How can I change this implementation to improve perfomance ? I does not have to be a list as long as it can be shared between threads and I can add at the end and take the first element (Queue)

```
public class DatabaseCache : ICacheDB
{
    private static List<NotificacionOrdenes> lstOrderToProcess;
    private static Object lockOrders;
    private static BackgroundWorker bgOrdenes;
    private static bool pendingOrders = false;
    private static Timer timerCheck;

    public DatabaseCache(string eventSourceName, bool monitorearOrderNotifications)
    {
        bgOrdenes = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgOrdenes.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgOrdenes_DoWork);

        lstOrderToProcess = new List<NotificacionOrdenes>();
        lockOrders = new Object();

        CheckOrderToProcess();

        if (!bgOrdenes.IsBusy)
        {
            bgOrdenes.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        //execute CheckOrderToProcess periodically
        timerCheck = new Timer(2000);
        timerCheck.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timerCheck_Elapsed);
        timerCheck.Enabled = true;
        timerCheck.AutoReset = true;

    }
    void timerCheck_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckOrderToProcess();
    }

    private void CheckOrderToProcess()
    {
        DataSet ds;
        NotificacionOrdenes notif;

        ds = Data.GetOrderNotifications_ToProcess();

        //if there is new info to process
        if ((ds != null) && (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0))
        {

            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                notif = new NotificacionOrdenes();

                //fill NOTIF with info of each row

                lock (lockOrders)
                {
                    lstOrderToProcess.Add(notif);
                }

            }

            pendingOrders = true;
        }
    }

    void bgOrdenes_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        NotificacionOrdenes notif;

        while (true)
        {
            if (pendingOrders)
            {
                lock (lockOrders)
                {
                    notif = lstOrderToProcess[0];
                    lstOrderToProcess.RemoveAt(0);

                    //check to see if there is any pending order
                    pendingOrders = lstOrderToProcess.Any();
                }

                //Execute rest of the logic
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see your timer being executed every 2 seconds - that's plenty orders of magnitudes somewhere else than what's time complexity of lock.
There is space for many improvements (basically implementing thread safe lock-free structure yourself by using an array and interlocked operations) - but I suspect that it would be pure premature optimization.
Are you sure that there is a high contention or performance bottleneck in the lock statements. If you are not sure than I would rather spend the extra time with profiling rather then with arbitrary optimization.

Comment: @Jan at some point I did chang the 2000 ms to 100ms and it made the performance worse. I have never implemented my own interlocked operations but I bet there is a library out there that I can reuse instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no conceivable reason to alter the locking in this code snippet.  It does however suffer from rather nasty design flaws:

- the wait loop inside DoWork is a *hot wait loop*.  It burns 100% core, accomplishing nothing 99.99999% of the time.  That's in general very unfriendly to the machine you run this code on.  It will also cause your program to be unresponsive to added items, even though you burn lots of cpu cycles on trying to detect that.  The operating system's thread scheduler will keep you in the dog house for a while after you burned your quantum.
- the *pendingOrders* variable is used as a synchronization object but is just a simple *bool* variable.  Lots of things go wrong when you do that.  For one, there are good odds that your code never sees the variable being set to true when you run the Release build of your code.  A problem in 32-bit code, such a variable must be declared *volatile*.  It is also inefficient, it can take a while before the thread can observe the assigned value.
- the use of lstOrderToProcess.Any() is inefficient.  No point in removing just the element at index 0 when you in effect will empty the entire list anyway.
- the consumer runs on a BackgroundWorker.  Which uses a thread-pool thread to implement the worker.  TP threads should in general not run for more than about half a second.  Your thread however runs forever, severe impeding the thread-pool scheduler's job to get pending tp thread requests executed.  This negatively affects the responsiveness of your entire app.

Get ahead by using a regular Thread to run the consumer.  And use a better design for the list, you want a *Blocking Queue*.  You can get one that runs on old .NET versions by using the code from the threading masters, Joe Duffy's [sample implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163427.aspx#S4) solves your hot wait-loop problem.  I'll repost it here, tweaked to not wait for the consumer:

```
public class BlockingQueue<T> { 
    private Queue<Cell<T>> m_queue = new Queue<Cell<T>>(); 
    public void Enqueue(T obj) { 
        Cell<T> c = new Cell<T>(obj);
        lock (m_queue) {
            m_queue.Enqueue(c); 
            Monitor.Pulse(m_queue); 
        }
    } 
    public T Dequeue() { 
        Cell<T> c; 
        lock (m_queue) { 
            while (m_queue.Count == 0) Monitor.Wait(m_queue); 
            c = m_queue.Dequeue();
        } 
        return c.m_obj; 
    } 
}

class Cell<T> { 
    internal T m_obj; 
    internal Cell(T obj) { 
        m_obj = obj;
    } 
}
```

Comment: The idea behing removing one item at at time is to infact make the list behave like a queue, If I remove all the items in the list how will I process them ?

Comment: You can simply reassign *lstOrderToProcess*.  But that wasn't the point of my answer, I **strongly** recommend using the BlockingQueue instead of the List.  You have to get rid of that hot wait loop.

Comment: In the link that you provided says "...Whenever a thread enqueues an element, it waits for a consumer to dequeue the element before returning. When a thread dequeues an element, should it find the buffer to be empty, it must wait for a new element to arrive. And of course after dequeueing, the consumer must signal the producer that it has taken its item" I dont need that I want the producer to be able to enqueue as much items as posible no matter how slow is the consumer

Comment: Just remove the Monitor.Wait() call in the Enqueue() method.

Comment: Hans thanks for your answer, it did improve somehow the performance, but considering there is only one producer and one consumer what other improvements can be made over you own answer ?

Comment: Ugh.  It is like driving into a Ferrari dealership with your Volkswagen Beetle, take a test-drive in a Spider and tell the salesman afterwards "that did improve over my Beetle somehow, what other improvements can be made?"  He'll roll his eyes and exclaim "how much faster does it need to be!"  Do you have any idea whatsoever?  Update your question with your methodology.

Comment: Hans well I need to process 700 request by minute and I am up to 600 . I can not have multiple consumers since the order in which the rows are consumed and executed need to be respected

Comment: The code I posted can handle hundreds of thousands of requests in a minute.  Having to guess where "600" comes from, that sounds a lot like a Volkswagen timer with an interval of 100 msec.

Comment: Hans I dont know if I mentioned it, but each request is being used to execute a stored procedure and I need to wait for the SP to finish before I call another one. The 100 ms timer is for the producer not for the consumer. The consumer is taking each item from the queue as fast as posible.

Answer (score 0):

If I would do producer/consumer in your case, then I would start from `List<>` as well.

But as I see it now, it's not the best case, because removing item from the list will cause indexes to be changed (and this required locking of the whole list).

Perhaps you could to use array instead? Something like this:

```
NotificacionOrdenes[] todo = new NotificacionOrdenes[1000];

// producer
// find empty slot (null) in todo somehow
todo[empty_slot] = new NotificacionOrdenes();
...

// consumer
// find non-empty slot somehow
var notif = todo[non_empty_slot]
todo[non_empty_slot] = null;
..
```

as you can see there is no need for lock (checking for null and setting to null are safe), but you have to handle situation when there are no empty slots, if array is too small, or consumer is too slow.

Comment: and no need for lock ?

Comment: @MauricioGracia, yep, or I would have plenty of minuses already =D

Comment: Be careful if you want to prevent a lot of headache!  
You don't need a lock, BUT(!) you need to ensure that acquiring and marking an item is an atomic operation, so instead of your last two lines you need:  
    var acquired;
    if(Interlocked.Exchange(ref todo[idx], null) != null) {/* Do your work */}  

Same way you need to ensure that only 1 producer can insert item into one empty slot.  

Be careful - Checking an array at specific index AND THEN reading it, or setting it IS NOT THREAD SAFE.

Comment: @Jan, thanks for commenting. My answer works for only 1 producer and 1 consumer, otherwise you need to synchronize (in case of multiple consumers - taking non-empty slot and setting it to null afterwards, this can be done by having another `object[] locks = new object[1000];`, used exclusively to lock access to the item (and not to the whole array, or use that `Exchange` function, which I am not familiar with yet).